# Audiokit AUv3 host get bpm

Tags: audiokit, business-process-management, auv3

I’m working in an Audiokit AUv3 app.
I have a simple question.
Is there any way to get bpm tempo from host when running as AUv3 on iOS?
Thanks a lot.